# Struts2 Ajax validation won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2, dojo

I decided to use Struts 2 DOJO plugin for the ajax validation of my forms.

I have:

- Added Struts2 dojo and json plugin to project
- Added '*jsonValidationWorkflowStack*' intercepter to my actions
- Included dojo taglib and `<sx:head />` tag on my page
- Included `<sx:submit validate="true" />` in my form

Now, after populating fields my form will not submit. No action will be performed.

I would also like to mention that I run my validation programatically, instead of xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOJO plugin is deprecated.

To make it work, however, you would need to set the `ajax` theme in struts.xml, or in `<sx:head />`, but this theme is deprecated too, and not even shipped anymore in the Struts2 jar.

Use [Struts2-jQuery plugin validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27863566/1654265) instead.

Also when talking about client-side validation, [reading this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341208/1654265).